# Ajax data not getting to controller? why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, serialization, controller

I am working with mvc4 application. I developed a form using .cshtml file, which inherits the model and has its corresponding controller action.
I am submitting the form using a ajax jquery like,

```
          var body=$('#formId').serialize();
          $.ajax({
                url: submitAction,
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "json",
                data: body,
               success: function (data) {
               if (data != null) {
                 alert("success");
               }
               });
```

"body" is fine and it has serialized data and the submitAction is the var which holds my controller action and the controll is transfered there.

EDIT:

My controller looks like,

```
    public JsonResult(ParentModel model) /*here model always hold null values, WHY??*/
    {
    //stmts..
    return Json(new {success=true}, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
    }
```

But, there the parameter of my controller action is showing null values. Can someone tell what could be the mistake and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   $.ajax({
     url: submitAction,
     type: "POST", <-- you make post, but asp.net mvc controller receives default GET request
    data: { model: body},

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult(string model) //<--now you pass string and to Deserialize in ParentModel 
 {
   JavaScriptSerializer jss= new JavaScriptSerializer();
   ParentModel pmodel = jss.Deserialize<ParentModel >(model); 

   return Json(new {success=true}, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
 }
```

Try edit `data:` section in you request,
remove datatype: "json"

And edit type `model` parameter to string

Comment: Sorry, its not making any difference. I'm afraid..;(

Comment: Its not working as it is giving the error of invalid Json Primitive while deserializing